Eigendecomposition of Hadamard Product of Matrices
Suppose we have matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, and their eigendecompositions are given as $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{Q}^{-1}$ and $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{P}\mathbf{D} \mathbf{P}^{-1}$. From this, can anything with regards to the eigendecomposition of the Hadamard product of the two matrices $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{A}\odot\mathbf{B}$ be determined, or do we have to start from scratch? Does it help at all if $\mathbf{A}$ or $\mathbf{B}$ have special properties (besides the trivial case of $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{1}$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the matrix consisting of all ones)?
The context of the problem is one I'm trying to solve with regards to shaping the ambiguity function of a given vector $\mathbf{x}$. The ambiguity function is given by:
$\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{A}((\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{A})\odot\mathbf{A}^H)\mathbf{A}^H $
where $\mathbf{A}$ is the $N\times N$ discrete Fourier transform matrix and $\mathbf{x}$ is the vector whose ambiguity function we wish to shape. My approach is to solve for $\mathbf{x}$, giving:
$\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^H = ((\mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{E}\mathbf{A})\odot\mathbf{A})\mathbf{A}^H $
Now the ambiguity function can be shaped by a matrix $\mathbf{W}$ consisting of ones and zeros
$\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^H = ((\mathbf{A}^H(\mathbf{W}\odot\mathbf{E})\mathbf{A})\odot\mathbf{A})\mathbf{A}^H $
To recover $\mathbf{x}$ from $((\mathbf{A}^H(\mathbf{W}\odot\mathbf{E})\mathbf{A})\odot\mathbf{A})\mathbf{A}^H $, we might take the first column, since, ideally, it is of the form $[x_1 x_1^*, x_2 x_1^*, ...]^T$. The vector will have a phase shift as well as an amplitude shift, but ideally this will just appear as a scalar multiplication of the desired ambiguity function.
In practice, this process must be done iteratively, since the aperiodic ambiguity function is desired, meaning that only the first $M$ where $2M-1 = N$ values are allowed to be nonzero. Also, $((\mathbf{A}^H(\mathbf{W}\odot\mathbf{E})\mathbf{A})\odot\mathbf{A})\mathbf{A}^H $ will generally not be in the form $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^H$. To minimize the difference $||\mathbf{x}_1\mathbf{x}_1^H-\mathbf{B}||$, $\mathbf{x}_1 = \sqrt{\lambda}\mathbf{u}$, where $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{u}$ is the associated eigenvector. Since this must be done every iteration of the optimization process, it becomes very expensive for large values of $N$.
